# Add duplicate records in json object array and remove last duplicate

Tags: javascript

I have json object array something like this

```
[{team: "C", side: "b", profit: "18"},
 {team: "C", side: "b", profit: "190"},
 {team: "A", side: "d", profit: "180"},{team: "C", side: "d", profit: "190"}]
```

I am looking for something like if two objects have same team and and side then their profit be added and last object is removed ,
something like in above array it would be,removing profit 190

```
 [{team: "C", side: "b", profit: "208"},{team: "A", side: "d", profit: "180"},{team: "C", side: "d", profit: "190"}],
```

I have tried following

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < data.length; j++) {
        if (data[i].team == data[j].team 
            && data[i].side == data[j].side) {
            data[i].profit =
                parseFloat(data[i].profit) + parseFloat(data[j].profit);
            data.splice(j, 1);

        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
console.log(data);
```

> If I take j=i+1 it works but it prints data as empty if there is only
>   one object inside array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using `reduce` method and `Map` and then get values.

```js
let data = [{team: "C", side: "b", profit: "18"}, {team: "C", side: "b", profit: "190"}, {team: "A", side: "d", profit: "180"},{team: "C", side: "d", profit: "190"}]
 
let result = data.reduce((r, {team, side, profit}) => {
  let key = `${team}|${side}`
  if(r.has(key)) r.get(key).profit += +profit
  else r.set(key, {team, side, profit: +profit})
  return r
}, new Map)

console.log([...result.values()])
```

Comment: This converts `profit` to a number though, I dunno if that's desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the items using an object. For each item, use a combination of `team` and `side` as the key. If they key does not exist, initialise the key in the object, with the initial value being the current item.

The next time the key is encountered, increment the profit.

At the end, use `Object.values` to get the resultant array.

Here's a sample snippet which does this using `Array.reduce`

```js
let input = [{
    team: "C",
    side: "b",
    profit: "18"
  },
  {
    team: "C",
    side: "b",
    profit: "190"
  },
  {
    team: "A",
    side: "d",
    profit: "180"
  },
  {
    team: "C",
    side: "d",
    profit: "190"
  }
];



const result = input.reduce((res, item) => {
  let key = item.team + "_" + item.side;
  if (!res[key]) {
    res[key] = item;
  } else {
    res[key].profit = Number(res[key].profit) + Number(item.profit) + "";
  }
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Comment: please see updated question ,team can be same but side can differ to

Comment: This will work then too, updated the input to match the one in question

Answer (score 0):

Mistake which you have done here is in the second loop condition
check here

```
var truthArray = [{team: "C", side: "b", profit: "18"},{team: "C", side: "b", profit: 
"190"},{team: "A", side: "d", profit: "180"}];
for(var i=0;i<truthArray.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<i;j++) {
        if((truthArray[i]["team"] === truthArray[j]["team"]) && (truthArray[i] ["side"] === truthArray[j]["side"])) {
            truthArray[i]["profit"] = (Number(truthArray[i]["profit"]) + Number(truthArray[j]["profit"])) + "";
            truthArray.splice(j, 1);
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is late, but this is another stylish answer that works very nice:

```
var a=[{team: "C", side: "b", profit: "18"},{team: "C", side: "b", profit: "190"},{team: "A", side: "d", profit: "180"}]

var result=a.reduce(function(ac,c,i,arr,j){
    p=c.team+"_"+c.side;
    j=ac[1][p];
    if(j==undefined) {
        ac[0].push(c);
        ac[1][p]=ac[0].length-1;
   } else ac[0][j].profit=ac[0][j].profit*1+c.profit*1;
    return ac;
}, [[],{}])[0];

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

You can check the result [online](https://jsbin.com/wiwemumizi/edit?output) (excuse me, I'm typing with my mobile phone and I don't have access to the code tools of stackoverflow editor.).

Answer (score 0):

```
result= []
done=[]
myData = [{team: "C", side: "b", profit: "18"},
 {team: "C", side: "b", profit: "190"},
 {team: "A", side: "d", profit: "180"}]
myData.forEach(function(item){
     if(done.indexOf(item.team+item.side)<0){
         sameSame = myData.filter(function(ele){
             return ele.team == item.team && ele.side == item.side
         })
         done.push(item.team+item.side)
         sum = 0
         sameSame.forEach(function(ele){
             sum = sum + parseInt(ele.profit)
         })
         result.push({team: item.team, side: item.side, profit: sum.toString()})
     }
 })
 console.log(result)
```